# d3.mouse(this) throws TypeError: t is null

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to add line mousehover action to my d3 bar-line chart. But at bottom of the code, d3.mouse(this) throwing type error.

Any idea?

Here is my code

```
  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("mouseover", function() {
        focus.style("display", null);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        div.transition()
            .duration(50)
            .style("opacity", 1e-6);
    })
    .on("mousemove", function(){
    //move focus around
        console.log(d3.mouse(this));
        var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]);
        var i  = bisectDate(data, x0, 1);

        var d0 = data[i - 1];
        var d1 = data[i];
        var d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    return;
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.accidents) + ")");
    div.transition()
        .duration(50)
        .style("opacity", .9);
      div.html("<h4>Company Name : <strong>"+ company_name +"</strong><br/> Date : <strong>"+ formatTime(d.date) +"</strong><br/>"+ bar_text +" : <strong>" + d.deaths + "<br/></strong>"+ line_text +" : <strong>"+ d.accidents +"</strong></h4>")
            .style("left","39%")
            .style("top", "160px");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the onmouse action has to be called onto an element that is selected by d3. I could not really use your code in fiddle but i didn't get mouse errors.

```
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg:svg')
 .attr('fill', 'blue');

 svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .attr("width", 333)
    .attr("height", 333)
    .on("mouseover", function() {
        focus.style("display", null);
    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fek9ddg5/309/